# How do I have multiple optional inputs?

Tags: python

```
import time

x = input("Buy Eggs? (Y/N) ")

if x.lower().strip() == "yes" or "y":
    print("Buy Eggs")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You bought eggs")

elif x.lower().strip() == "no" or "n":
    print("Don't buy eggs")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("You don't have eggs")
```

What I want to happen is to allow multiple words to be inputted for one `if` command. I thought it'd work but instead of working it would prioritize the top piece of code.

```
Buy Eggs? (Y/N) n #<--- Answer#
Buy Eggs
You bought eggs

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It only seems to work if I remove the `or` command but I haven't found any other options to allow multiple optional inputs.

Thank you if you do choose to help me

Comment: Try like this `x.lower().strip() in ["yes", "y"]`

Comment: Actually, you'll see a bunch of different options, like `x in ["yes", "y"]` or `x in ("yes", "y")`, but you *should* use `x in {"yes", "y"}` instead, for performance reasons (assuming you care about performance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you:

```
ans = input("Buy Eggs? (Y/N) ")

if ans.lower().strip() in ('y', 'yes'):
    print("Buy Eggs")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You bought eggs")

elif ans.lower().strip() in ('n', 'no'):
    print("Don't buy eggs")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("You don't have eggs")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give the multiple inputs in a list :

```
import time

x = input("Buy Eggs? (Y/N) ")

if x in ["yes",'y', "Y", "yea"]:
    print("Buy Eggs")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You bought eggs")

elif x in ["no", "n", "NO", "N"]:
    print("Don't buy eggs")
    time.sleep(.5)
    print("You don't have eggs")
```